# How to reassign unique_ptr in a different scope?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Obj {
    public:
        Obj(int x) : x(x) {}
        int x;
};

void func(unique_ptr<Obj> o) {
    o = make_unique<Obj>(new Obj(5));
}

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Obj> o;
    func(o);
    cout << o->x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But it returns:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void func(std::unique_ptr<Obj>)’:
main.cpp:21:9: error: ‘make_unique’ was not declared in this scope
     o = make_unique<Obj>(new Obj(5));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
     o = make_unique<Obj>(new Obj(5));
                        ^
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Obj; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
     func(o);
```

How can I reassign the pointer in the function?

**EDIT:**

I also tried:

```
void func(unique_ptr<Obj> o) {
    o.reset(new Obj(5));
}
```

Which returns this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:27:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Obj; _Dp = std::default_delete]’
     func(o);
           ^
```

Comment: 1. You didn't `#include <memory>` 2. Your `func` would only reassign its local pointer if it compiled. 3. Your `main` has multiple issues, including trying to convert  a `Obj` to a `std::unique_ptr<Obj>` which doesn't work

Comment: I edited my post, made it in haste, sorry.

Comment: You cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr` so your `func` makes very little sense. Maybe you meant to take the `std::unique_ptr` by reference?

Comment: `void func(unique_ptr<Obj>& o) {  o.reset(new Obj(5)); }`  because you need pass argument by a reference & and not by value (copy constructor is deleted for unique_ptr). In any case your design is totally wrong. If you really need reset - return pointer directly from the function, and then use it. Do not pass smart pointer as an argument.

Comment: Thanks @VictorGubin

Comment: I mean `Obj* new_object_factory_method( ... ) {  return new Object(); }; o.reset( new_object_factory_method() );`.

Comment: U'v got multiple issues. Missed reference syntax, rvalue-ref/move semantics, unique_ptr semantics... A proper answer shall be very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a mutable reference parameter, and an "in/out" or "update" parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Obj {
public:
    Obj(int x) : x(x) {}
    int x;
};

void func(unique_ptr<Obj>& o) {
    o = make_unique<Obj>(5);
}

int main() {
    unique_ptr<Obj> o;
    func(o);
    cout << o->x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But what you also consider doing is:

- avoid `using namespace std;`
- avoid in/out parameters; prefer return values
- avoid shadowing variables
- enable all your compiler warnings you can tolerate; fix the code causing warnings
- `const` correctness

`clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-c99-compat -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,null -std=c++17 -cxx-isystem /usr/local/include a.cpp -o a.out`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::make_unique;
using std::unique_ptr;

namespace {

class Obj {
    int _x;
public:
    Obj(int x) : _x{x} {}
    int x() const { return _x; }
};

unique_ptr<Obj> func() {
    return make_unique<Obj>(5);
}

} // anon

int main() {
    auto o = func();
    cout << o->x() << "\n";
}
```